# How do I update a query from Google App Engine NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

We are using Google App Engine in Python. I have code that saves a new object to the database, and then queries the database to receive all the objects. The problem is that the query returns all the objects except the new object I created. Only after refreshing the page I see the new object. Is there a way to update the query to include all the objects, including the new object I created? Here is my code:

```
if (self.request.get("add_a_new_feature") == "true"):
    features = Feature.gql("WHERE feature_name=:1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 1", NEW_FEATURE_NAME) # class Feature inherits from ndb.Model
    if (features.count() == 0):
        new_feature = Feature(feature_name=NEW_FEATURE_NAME)
        new_feature.put()
...
features = Feature.gql("ORDER BY date_created")
if (features.count() > 0):
    features_list = features.fetch()
    for feature in features_list:
        ... # the list doesn't contain new_feature
```

Comment: You need to read up on eventual consistency to understand what is going on, this is "expected" behaviour.  

Given you have just saved the object, why query for it again ?

Comment: @TimHoffman There can be several features and I need the list of all of them, to display them in the page. If I added a new feature, I want it to be included as the last feature in the list.

Comment: you already have it, just use it directly rather then getting it again (and failing) from the datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - this is an expected behaviour. [Take a look at this article for additional information.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) As a quick fix/hack you could simply get the data from datastore before adding the new entity and then append it to the list.

```
features = Feature.gql("ORDER BY date_created")

if (self.request.get("add_a_new_feature") == "true"):
    if (Feature.gql("WHERE feature_name=:1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 1", NEW_FEATURE_NAME).count() == 0):
        new_feature = Feature(feature_name=NEW_FEATURE_NAME)
        new_feature.put()
        features.append(new_feature)
...

if (features.count() > 0):
    features_list = features.fetch()
    for feature in features_list:
        ... # the list now contain the new_feature at the end
```

Depending on what `Entity.gql()` returns when there are no results (None or [ ]?) you may need to check whether `features` is a list before appending. You could also probably avoid the second query since you already have a list of features and could loop through it in Python rather than sending another request to datastore.

Comment: Ah... apparently `Entity.gql()` returns a GqlQuery object and not the results which you then need to `fetch()` but you get the idea...

Comment: The link you provided is related to DB Datastore API, but I'm using NDB Datastore API. Can you provide a link related to NDB Datastore API?